# yii2 App Starting With An Error

Tags: yii2

I am experiencing a strange error when I start my Yii2 app! Please need your help on this. Here is the what I get:

```
     PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
```

mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
1. in /var/www/yii2/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseStringHelper.php at line 31
22232425262728293031323334353637383940

{
    /**
     * Returns the number of bytes in the given string.
     * This method ensures the string is treated as a byte array by using `mb_strlen()`.
     * @param string $string the string being measured for length
     * @return integer the number of bytes in the given string.
     */
    public static function byteLength($string)
    {
        return mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.
     * This method ensures the string is treated as a byte array by using `mb_substr()`.
     * @param string $string the input string. Must be one character or longer.
     * @param integer $start the starting position
     * @param integer $length the desired portion length. If not specified or `null`, there will be
     * no limit on length i.e. the output will be until the end of the strin
```

Answer (score 3):

I happened an the same error message copying an external component in my project in my case I solved the problem by running

```
   composer update
```

Comment: You can use upvote per Answer if you found it useful

Comment: I would like to, but vote up requires 15 reputation. That was my first post.

Comment: Thank for the reply I hope you became a good Yii2st in short time, good work